# How to remove all records of the table in Hybris?

Tags: java, mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

In my development environment, I have added wrong data to my custom ItemType. Now I want to remove all data for that Type. Basically I want to truncate my ItemType table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run the below Impex (Change `MyItemType` with your ItemType)

```
$targetType=MyItemType
REMOVE $targetType[batchmode=true];itemtype(code)[unique=true]
;$targetType
```

---

You can also run SQL query from HAC, refer [**this post**](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/how-remove-update-data-records-hybris-itemtype-hac.html) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. As mentioned in post, I'll try SQL query to correct my data.

Comment: I am glad that post helps you!! If you need more help, edit the question with more details, I am happy to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this using commit mode on SQL Query in hac by giving TypePkString as input

```
delete FROM itemtype WHERE (TypePkString='8796149088338')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).